# Telescoping property: $\sum_{k \geq 0}\frac{1}{(4k+1)(4k+3)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to calculate the sum
$$\sum_{k \geq 0}\frac{1}{(4k+1)(4k+3)}$$

I've made some attempts to transform this in a summation that I could apply the telescopic property, but I didnt have any success.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: $2\frac{1}{(4k+1)(4k+3)} = \frac{1}{4k+1}-\frac{1}{4k+3}$

Comment: I'm getting that you won't be able to find the sum using telescoping methods...

Comment: Fredréric this is false

Comment: @AaronMaroja No, he has it right.

Comment: I read hint 2, instead of 2 times..., my bad, it's correct

Comment: i'm still trying, see if that this helps $\frac{1}{2} \sum \frac{ (-1)^{k}}{2k+1} = \sum \frac{1}{(4k+1)(4k+3)}$

Answer (score 2):

First notice that

$\sum \frac{1}{(4k+1)(4k+3)} = \frac{1}{2} \sum \frac{2}{(4k+1)(4k+3)} = \frac{1}{2} \sum \frac{1}{(4k+1)} - \frac{1}{4k+3} =\frac{1}{2} \sum \frac{(-1)^{k}}{2k+1} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{\pi}{8}$

To know why $\sum \frac{(-1)^{k}}{2k+1} = \frac{\pi}{4} $ check [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14815/why-does-this-converge-to-pi-4).

Comment: remove space between `]` and `(` in your link if you want it to appear as [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14815/why-does-this-converge-to-pi-4)

Comment: I can't find what's wrong in this calculation to deserve a downvote. Can the downvoter elaborate?