# Why is $1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+\cdots = \frac{\pi}{4}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, closed-form, pi

I was watching a numberphile video, and it stated that the limit of  $1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+\cdots$ was $\frac \pi 4.$

I was just wondering if anybody could prove this using some terms and math ***I* am likely to understand**. I am a high school student taking Algebra II.

Comment: I am afraid that you need calculus to understand the proof.

Comment: I think there are some elementary ways of deriving the arctangent series.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : There are particular proofs that cannot be understood without calculus. Can you prove the non-existence of a different proof for which knowledge of derivatives (etc.) is not needed?

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I didn't claim that. Anyway, $\pi$ being a transcendental number, the recourse to infinity seems unavoidable. The historical discovery was based on integral calculus.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849348/geometric-intuition-for-pi-4-1-1-3-1-5-cdots

Comment: This is also related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14815/why-does-this-converge-to-pi-4

Comment: @Watson I imagine that choice of link will be the best we'll get.

Comment: It surprises me that you would even be able to comprehend an infinite series to the level needed to understand this sum, so good luck and I do hope you become awesome at math.

Comment: If I may incline you, the geometric series is far simpler... and then you should learn calculus ( calculus is honestly not too bad ) and combine the two, you can derive things like this (with some effort).

Comment: @Travis: without trigonometry it is even more challenging to explain you :( But what do you know about $\pi$, then ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, it's the ratio of a circles circumference to it's diameter ie: $C = \pi\times d$ $\pi \approx 3.14159653589\ldots$ It's an irrational number, it can't be represented as $\frac{p}{q}$

Comment: By the way, if you ever want to chat with me personally on things that may seem less answerable, like this question, or if you want to learn some calculus, I don't mind chatting with you.  I use Discord btw.

Comment: Thanks, @SimpleArt, I'm not sure if I ever will, but I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: :-P It's also on my profile page if you ever forget how to find me.  And I'm on the "users" tab.  :-)  Ranking pretty high this year.

Comment: This is simply the [Dirichlet $\beta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function) evaluated at $n=1.~$ In general, all values of this function at odd values of its argument yield rational multiples of powers of $\pi,$ i.e., $\dfrac{\beta(2k+1)}{\pi^{2k+1}}\in\mathbb Q.~$ Related concepts are the [Dirichlet $\eta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function), for which $\dfrac{\eta(2k)}{\pi^{2k}}\in\mathbb Q,~$ and the [Riemann $\zeta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function), for which $\dfrac{\zeta(2k)}{\pi^{2k}}\in\mathbb Q.$

Comment: You're using the term "limit" incorrectly. The title of your question should be: Why is $1-1/3+1/5-1/7+\cdots = \pi/4?$ Either that or "Why is $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k}1/(2k+1) = \pi/4?$

Comment: @YvesDaoust : You said you NEED calculus. And that historically it came from integral calculus. Can you be specific about the historical claim?

Comment: @MichaelHardy: no harassment please.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am doing my best to only use simple notions, but the explanation will look very strange and indirect. We will start with geometry.

[image]

On the figure you see two right triangles, of basis $1$ and height $x$ and $x+h$ respectively. Note that $x$ and $h$ are line segments, while $y$ and $g$ arc circular arcs. We are particularly interested in the relation between the values of $y$ and $x$, which we will study by observing how the height difference $h$ makes the corresponding arc length $g$ vary.

By Pythagoras, the hypothenuses of the small triangle is $\sqrt{1+x^2}$, which is also the radius of the large circle. Then the arc facing $g$ on the larger circle has a length of $g\sqrt{1+x^2}$; if you straighten it, it becomes the base of the small outer triangle, which by proportionality has the length $(g\sqrt{1+x^2})\sqrt{1+x^2}$.

So we have established

$$\frac{g}{h}\approx\frac1{1+x^2}.$$

This relation is quite approximate in the figure, but if you make $h$ smaller and smaller, it becomes more and more accurate, because the arcs become more and more straight.

Actually, we just computed a *derivative*, i.e. the ratio of a variation of $y$ (from $y$ to $y+g$) over a variation of $x$ (from $x$ to $x+h$). This is a notion from calculus.

Now we want to express the relation between $x$ and $y$ and we will assume that it is of the polynomial type:

$$y(x)=a+bx+cx^2+dx^3+ex^4\cdots$$ without specifying the final degree. Using this formula, let us evaluate the ratio $g/h$, i.e.

$$\frac gh=\frac{y(x+h)-y(x)}h=\frac{a-a+b(x+h-x)+c((x+h)^2-x^2)+d((x+h)^3-x^3)+\cdots}h$$

For example, the cubic term gives, using a remarkable product

$$\frac{(x+h)^3-x^3}h=\frac{(x+h-x)((x+h)^2+(x+h)x+x^2)}h=(x+h)^2+(x+h)x+x^2.$$

If we again decrease $h$ so that it becomes neglectible compared to $x$, we obtain $3x^3$. Repeating this reasoning with all terms, you can check that we will get the polynomial expression

$$\frac gh=b+2cx+3\,dx^2+4\,dx^3+5\,dx^4+\cdots$$

We would like to compare it to the previous expression, which unfortunately is not in a polynomial form. We can achieve this goal by using the "geometric progression" formula.

Let us consider the numbers $(-x^2)^k$ and compute their sum for $k$ from $0$ to $n$:

$$S_n=1-x^2+x^4-\cdots(-x^2)^n.$$

Then if we multiply the sum by $-x^2$ and subtract, we obtain after a lot of terms cancellation

$$(1+x^2)S_n=1-(-x^2)^{n+1},$$ so that

$$S_n=1-x^2+x^4-\cdots(-x^2)^n=\frac{1-(-x^2)^{n+1}}{1+x^2}.$$

If $x^2<1$, then $(x^2)^n$ becomes smaller and smaller so that we can simplify

$$S_n=1-x^2+x^4-\cdots(-x^2)^n\approx\frac1{1+x^2},$$ and the larger the final degree, the better the approximation. The figure shows the matching of the polynomial of degree $10$ with the exact formula.

[image]

Now we are able to compare the formulas for $g/h$, and by identification,

$$b=1,c=0,d=-\frac13,e=0,f=\frac15,\cdots$$

Then, noting that $y(0)=0$, we also have $a=0$ and we establish the famous Gregory series,
$$y(x)=x-\frac{x^3}3+\frac{x^5}5-\frac{x^7}7+\cdots$$
 which is illustrated in the next picture (to degree $11$). It develops the so-called arc tangent function:

[image]

Finally, we can observe that when $x=1$, the arc $y$ covers an eighth of the circumference, hence the Leibnitz formula

$$\frac\pi4=1-\frac13+\frac15-\frac17+\cdots$$

---

The attentive reader may have noticed a little twist in the explanation. While obtaining the formula for $1/(1+x^2)$, we assumed that $x^2<1$, but later used $x=1$. For reasons that deserve many more explanations, the "polynomial" expression for $y(x)$ is still valid for $x=1$.

Comment: As far as I know, $\arctan x=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\dotsb$ is due to Gregory and $\frac{\pi}{4}=1-\frac{1}{3}+\dotsb$ is due to Leibniz.

Comment: @egreg: you are right, fixing.

Comment: I have added a new answer, which I believe to be simpler. http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2093056/65203

Comment: :D thank you for your great effort!

Answer (score 3):

If you have covered $$\arctan x=x-\dfrac{x^3}{3}+\dfrac{x^5}{5}-\dfrac{x^7}{7}+\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}\dfrac{x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}+\cdots\quad |x|\le 1$$ then, for $x=1$ $$\frac{\pi}{4}=\arctan 1=1-\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{5}-\dfrac{1}{7}+\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}\dfrac{1}{2n-1}+\cdots$$ $$$$

Comment: I haven't covered $\tan$ and $\arctan$ yet, is there a more elementary way to prove it?

Comment: Have you covered derivatives of power series?

Comment: @Alone OP has stated that he is in algebra2 in highschool (*or middleschool depending on country*) and has just implied that he hasn't even touched trigonometry yet (*which I find odd, usually those are taught in algebra2 where I'm from*), so no... he wouldn't have even heard of a power series nor would he have any knowledge of derivatives.

Comment: @Alone He has said that he is in Algebra.

Comment: JMoravitz and Simple Art are right, I haven't touch calculus or trigonometry *yet*, pretty sure it's at least touched on later in the year

Comment: Is it possible to derive the formula without making an appeal to trigonometry or calculus?

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern All that's left is an appeal to authority :P

Comment: All right, sorry, I didn't noticed that Travis had mentioned "Algebra II".