# Why $1+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+\cdots=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, closed-form, pi

Wikipedia's List of formulae involving $\pi$ claims
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{(n^2-n)/2}}{2n+1}=1+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+\cdots=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}$$
and cites Chrystal's Algebra, but I don't have access to that. How can we prove the identity?

It is similar to the famous
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}=\frac{\pi}{4}$$
([Why is $1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+\cdots = \frac{\pi}{4}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2092423/why-is-1-frac13-frac15-frac17-cdots-frac-pi4)) but the signs are changed. Does it follow from that famous one by some clever series manipulation?

Comment: *but I don't have access to that* --- Many copies of several different editions of Chrystal's "Algebra" are freely available on the internet (google-books, internet archive, and probably other places). Actually, Chrystal wrote TWO different algebra texts, and the one you DON'T want is his "Introduction to Algebra" (first published in 1898).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the expansion of $$\frac{1+x^2}{1+x^4}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k(x^{4k}+x^{4k+2})$$
Integrating gives $$\begin{align}\int_0^x\frac{1+t^2}{1+t^4}\,dt&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\left(\frac{x^{4k+1}}{4k+1}+\frac{x^{4k+3}}{4k+3}\right)\\&=\frac{x}1+\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^5}5-\frac{x^7}7+\cdots\end{align}$$
Substituting $x=1$ gives $$\int_0^1\frac{1+x^2}{1+x^4}\,dx=\frac11+\frac13-\frac15-\frac17+\cdots$$
This integral comes to $$\begin{align} \int_0^1\frac{1+x^2}{1+x^4}\,dx&=\frac12\int_0^1\frac1{x^2+\sqrt2x+1}+\frac1{x^2-\sqrt2x+1}\,dx\\&=\frac12\int_0^1\frac1{\left(x+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^2+\frac12}+ \frac1{\left(x-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^2+\frac12}\,dx\\&=\left[\frac{\arctan\left(\sqrt2x+1\right)+ \arctan\left(\sqrt2x-1\right)}{\sqrt2}\right]_0^1\\&=\frac{\arctan\left(\sqrt2+1\right)+\arctan\left(\sqrt2-1\right)-\arctan(1)-\arctan(-1)}{\sqrt2}\\&=\frac{\frac38\pi+\frac18\pi-\frac14\pi+\frac14\pi}{\sqrt2}\\&=\boxed{\frac\pi{2\sqrt2}}\end{align}$$
as required.